# Conditional 'with' tag in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django (and Python) for the first time, and I'm looking for the correct solution to an included template that may or may not have been provided with a value.

For example, this template will always have a 'company' defined, but it might not always have a 'user' defined. If the 'user' is not defined, then one should be defined, like so:

```
<% with guy=(user if user != None else company.admin_user) %>
```

But I haven't found a good way to accomplish this. In some cases a user will be defined by the includer of the template, in other cases the template should have to find a 'default' user.

**Edit:** The solution, as per Ignacio's answer, is this:

```
<% with guy=user|default:company.admin_user %>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want the [`default`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#default) filter.

Comment: This variable, `guy` from the example, is used in many places in the template. Is there a way to use the default filter to define it once? I'd like to avoid having to declare a default for every use of the variable.

Comment: I can't remember if filters work with `with`. You may need to try the old syntax.

Comment: Sorry - I'm very new to both Python and Django - what is the old syntax? I'm not looking for a more efficient way of accomplishing this task, just a way that works. :)

Comment: ["**Note** The previous more verbose format is still supported: {% with business.employees.count as total %}"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with)

Comment: Ah, sorry again, I think I was being dense. That works great! (Updated question with the solution as per your suggestion)